# I want to support multiple live-streamed video services using [Agora.io]

Tags: agora.io

Below is a use case of our business. I appreciate if you can tell if the [agora.io] platform can support this use case and how i.e., (Options, SDK, APIs)

This is an online 1:1 class for lecturer and students.

The lecturer opens a virtual space for class and invites 1 student.

Student has 2 webcams. One is installed on the front, and the other is installed on the side.

Videos from student's webcams should be live-streamed with no delay to the lecturer.

the lecturer can select between two videos of student and watch videos and listen to the audio two live-streamed videos must be switched by a button and the switched video is played on the lecturer's Screen.

#1 live-streamed video -> button click -> #2 live-streamed video -> button click -> #1 live-streamed video --> button click --> #2 live-streamed video ...

When switching between #1 live-streamed video and #2 live-streamed video, the "Playback Position" must be the same.

At any time, the lecturer can end the video session. the videos of each student must be ready immediately at the server to replay and watch. The lecturer can end lesson

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about ***[what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)***, and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ community would be able to help you find a platform that accomplishes all of this if you find that agora.io is unable to.

Answer (score 0):

Agora can totally support this use case.

You can use the RTC SDK to start a video call. Here is the quick start guide for that: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/start_call_web?platform=Web.

To switch the camera, you can take a look at this article: https://docs.agora.io/en/faqs/switchdevice_web#for-versions-earlier-than-v250. You might need to use RTM SDK to send a signal from teacher's side to student's side which can trigger the switch camera operation. Here is the RTM quick start: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/messaging_web?platform=Web.

To replay the videos, you need to use the Cloud Recording API to store the videos on an external cloud storage, for example, Amazon S3. Here is the document for Cloud Recording: https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/product_cloud_recording?platform=Linux.