# Agora: Multiple cameras from the source - Is it possible to stream both views?

Tags: video-streaming, agora.io

Tinkering with the Agora API. The use case is thus:

Setup: Laptop webcam, and an iphone connected via USB overlooking the keyboard. (2 cameras)

Video call -> Teacher & Student.

Expected behavior -> Student needs to see both the views - The laptop webcam output & the iphone camera output simultaneously (as 2 windows on the student canvas).

Is this possible to do this on Agora Video API's?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question, which appears to have the answer you're looking for? best of luck, Alan
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62844623/i-want-to-support-multiple-live-streamed-video-services-using-agora-io